# Button Content Not Updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Style-1
Please Check both styles

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react'
class Click extends Component {

    buttonRef = createRef();
    updatedValue = 0;

    clickCounter = () => {
        this.updatedValue = this.buttonRef.current.value++;
        console.log("upDatedValue outside of render() method= "+ this.updatedValue)
        }

    render() {
        console.log("upDatedValue inside of render() method= "+ this.updatedValue);
        return (
            <div>
                <button ref={this.buttonRef} onClick={this.clickCounter}>
                    Clicked {this.updatedValue} Times</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Click
```

Style-2

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react'

class Click extends Component {

    buttonRef = createRef();
    updatedValue = 0;

    render() {
        let clickCounter = () => {
        this.updatedValue = this.buttonRef.current.value++;
        console.log("upDatedValue inside of cliclCounter() method= "+ this.updatedValue);
        
        }
        console.log("upDatedValue inside of render() method= "+ this.updatedValue);
        return (
            <div>
                <button ref={this.buttonRef} onClick={clickCounter}>
                    Clicked {this.updatedValue} Times</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Click
```

None of these approach is not working. It always show "Clicked 0 Times"
Can anyone please explain why this is not working and what the solution is.
Thank you.
-Samiul Fahad

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the state of your counter. Here's a solution, since you are using class based components:

```js
class Click extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      updatedValue: 0
    }

    this.clickCounter = this.clickCounter.bind(this);
  }

    clickCounter(){
        this.setState({updatedValue: this.state.updatedValue+1})
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.clickCounter}>
                    Clicked {this.state.updatedValue} Times</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Click />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes I know that. But I want to solve that using Ref. I don't want to use state here. I think you have got it. I want it solved using Ref.

Comment: I don't thinks there is a good way around this other than using a state. You should at least be aware of that

Comment: Yes I agree. But I want to know why that approach is not working.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: Ah okay. Render is called when react component is first instantiated, or when there is a new update to the component state. Since you have no state, and no state to update, it will only be called when the component is instantiated.

Comment: Your statement is not 100% Correct. Please check this video. First 6minutes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4okzJc6_Ak

Comment: Sorry... check the comment.. I have edited it